# How to see the details of Spring Batch on UI?

Tags: spring-batch

I am using **Spring Batch** and my org not willing to use **Spring Cloud Data Flow**, is there any way we can create UI and show details of batch job and somehow also restart the batch Job?

Comment: SCDF are just two jars. Download and run them. You don need any installations for them.

Comment: Can you share why SCDF is not an option for your org? Otherwise you can take a look at https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin.

Comment: Can you share a link where Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Data Flow explain and demoed well?